# Changing Stroke color of a textInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

when an error occurs (for example when the user inputs invalid name (inserting symbols such as:@$ etc..) ,i want to make the stroke color of the textBox to be red , how can i do that, here's my textbox code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/etFullNameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Full Name"
    android:textColorHint="#b4ffff"
    app:startIconTint="#b4ffff"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_person"
    app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/color_on_secondary" 

    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etFullName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default stroke color with an error is red.
You can in any case customize it using the **`boxStrokeErrorColor`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/..." 
    ...>
```

Then you have to provide your custom validation. Something like:

```
    etFullName.addTextChangedListener(
        afterTextChanged = {
            if (!isValid(it)){
                etFullNameLayout.error = "Error!"
            }
        }
    )
```

[image]